# Can we leverage Object Search in Einstein Bot Dialog to query External Object records returned by Federated Search?

Tags: einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots, bots, chatbot, federated-search

We need to bring Federated Search results into chat bot dialogs.

Is Object Search action can be leveraged for that or any other configuration (no code) option?

Answer (score 0):

No, Object Search (beta) action cannot be leveraged to bring Federated Search results into chat bot dialogs.

The [documentation page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_deliver_knowledge_articles.htm&type=5) includes limitation for supported objects:

> Object Search supports the following standard objects: Account, Case,
> Contact, Campaign, Contract, Knowledge, Lead, Opportunity, Order, Task
> Object Search supports the following standard field types:
> Auto-Number, Birthday, Boolean, Content, Currency (including Currency
> ISO Code), Date, DateTime, Double, Due Date, Email, Entity ID, Enums
> (dynamic, static), Fax, Integer, Long, Multi-line Text, Percent, Phone
> Number, Record Type, String Plus Clob (text only), Text, URL Note NOTE
> Object Search doesn’t support rich text, long text, or text area field
> types.

So the only option would be an Apex action with SOSL search like following

`FIND {AWS} RETURNING Blog__x (DisplayUrl, ExternalId, Title__c, Summary__c, Date__c)`

for example of jitendra blog federated search implementation.